# Bootstrap 4 navbar pushing content down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

The issue that I'm having is that the content on my page is being pushed down by the navbar creating a small scroll gap at the bottom of the page.

[image]

I'd like to have all the content fill the page without the unnecessary scroll bar in the above image. The navbar at the top of the page is a basic Bootstrap navbar with the body making use of this code I copied from [Bootsnipp](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/BDWlD) consisting of a side navigation and content area, which I have modified and added a responsive toggle button.

The issue is being caused by applying `position: absolute` to `#sidebar-wrapper` which fixes the side nav to the top of the page. I have tried changing the order and positioning of the layout as well as placing the header-navbar and content inside of a wrapper with little success.

[image]

The above gif is the issue that I was having before applying `position: absolute` although this is only a temporary fix as when the window is resized vertically the side-nav doesn't stay fixed to the bottom of the page.

Below is a snippet of the view in question.

Thank you for your time and I will be happy to provide any further information if needed

```js
var AccountNav = (function() {

  var wWidth

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#submenu-toggle').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled')
    })

    getWindowWidth()
    ToggleNavBar()
  })

  $(window).resize(function() {
    getWindowWidth()
    console.log(wWidth)
    ToggleNavBar()
  })

  function ToggleNavBar() {
    if (wWidth >= 768) {
      $('#toggle-navbar').css("display", "none")
    } else {
      $('#toggle-navbar').css("display", "flex")
      if ($('#wrapper').hasClass('toggled')) {
        $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled')
      }
    }
  }

  function getWindowWidth() {
    wWidth = $(window).width()
  }

})();
```

```css
html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#wrapper {
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
  padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 250px;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -250px;
}


/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  text-indent: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: #fff
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand a {
  color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
  #wrapper {
    padding-left: 250px;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 0;
  }
  #page-content-wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark py-1">
      <div class="container">

        <!-- Brand -->
        <a asp-controller="home" asp-action="index" class="navbar-brand">
          <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" style="  enable-background: new 0 0 32 32;" xml:space="preserve" fill="white">
     <g id="logo" class="logo">
     <path d="M2 20h20v2H2v-2zm2-8h2v7H4v-7zm5 0h2v7H9v-7zm4 0h2v7h-2v-7zm5 0h2v7h-2v-7zM2 7l10-5 10 5v4H2V7zm2 1.236V9h16v-.764l-8-4-8 4zM12 8a1 1 0 1 1 0-2 1 1 0 0 1 0 2z" />

     </g>
    </svg> BankNet
        </a>

        <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="nav-link">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Features" class="nav-link">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="false" aria-expanded="false">
        Utilities
       </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <a asp-controller="Utilities" asp-action="CurrencyConverter" class="dropdown-item">Currency Converter</a>
                <a asp-controller="Utilities" asp-action="TaxCalculator" class="dropdown-item">Tax Calculator</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li href="#" class="nav-link">
              <a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Account" class="nav-link">Account</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main role="main" class="pb-3">
    <nav class="navbar p-1" id="toggle-navbar">
      <div class="nav-item">
        <a class="btn btn-dark text-light" id="submenu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="sidebar-wrapper" style="position:absolute">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
          <li class="sidebar-brand">
            Hello {Name}
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#Accounts">Accounts</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#Transfers">Transfers</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#Loans">Loans</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#Options">Account options</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <h1>Hello World</h1>
              <h1>Hello World</h1>
              <h1>Hello World</h1>
              <h1>Hello World</h1>
              <h1>Hello World</h1>
              <h1>Hello World</h1>
              <h1>Hello World</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </main>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed your navbar position css to fixed, i hope this is the solution that you are looking for

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar--fixed navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark py-1">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand -->
                <a asp-controller="home" asp-action="index" class="navbar-brand">
                    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                        x="0px" y="0px" width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32"
                        style="enable-background: new 0 0 32 32;" xml:space="preserve" fill="white">
                        <g id="logo" class="logo">
                            <path
                                d="M2 20h20v2H2v-2zm2-8h2v7H4v-7zm5 0h2v7H9v-7zm4 0h2v7h-2v-7zm5 0h2v7h-2v-7zM2 7l10-5 10 5v4H2V7zm2 1.236V9h16v-.764l-8-4-8 4zM12 8a1 1 0 1 1 0-2 1 1 0 0 1 0 2z" />
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                    BankNet
                </a>

                <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Features" class="nav-link">Features</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                                data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="false" aria-expanded="false">
                                Utilities
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <a asp-controller="Utilities" asp-action="CurrencyConverter"
                                    class="dropdown-item">Currency Converter</a>
                                <a asp-controller="Utilities" asp-action="TaxCalculator" class="dropdown-item">Tax
                                    Calculator</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li href="#" class="nav-link">
                            <a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Account" class="nav-link">Account</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main role="main" class="pb-3">
        <nav class="navbar p-1" id="toggle-navbar">
            <div class="nav-item">
                <a class="btn btn-dark text-light" id="submenu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
                <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                    <li class="sidebar-brand">
                        Hello {Name}
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#Accounts">Accounts</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#Transfers">Transfers</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#Loans">Loans</a>
                    </li>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#Options">Account options</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="page-content-wrapper">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <h1>Hello World</h1>
                            <h1>Hello World</h1>
                            <h1>Hello World</h1>
                            <h1>Hello World</h1>
                            <h1>Hello World</h1>
                            <h1>Hello World</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>

<style>
    html,
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    .navbar--fixed {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1100;
    }

    #toggle-navbar {
        position: fixed;
        height: 110px;
        background: white;
        z-index: 1050;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #submenu-toggle {
        margin-top: 64px;
    }

    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 0;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled {
        padding-left: 250px;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        z-index: 1000;
        position: fixed;
        left: 250px;
        width: 0;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        margin-left: -250px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        background: #000;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #page-content-wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 15px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        position: absolute;
        margin-right: -250px;
    }

    /* Sidebar Styles */

    .sidebar-nav {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 250px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }

    .sidebar-nav li {
        text-indent: 20px;
        line-height: 40px;
    }

    .sidebar-nav li a {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #999999;
    }

    .sidebar-nav li a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    }

    .sidebar-nav li a:active,
    .sidebar-nav li a:focus {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand {
        height: 65px;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 60px;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand a {
        color: #999999;
    }

    .sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand a:hover {
        color: #fff;
        background: none;
    }

    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        #sidebar-wrapper {
            height: calc(100vh - 110px);
            margin-top: 110px;
        }

        .container-fluid {
            margin-top: 110px;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .sidebar-nav {
            margin-top: 64px;
        }

        #wrapper {
            padding-left: 250px;
        }

        #wrapper.toggled {
            padding-left: 0;
        }

        #sidebar-wrapper {
            width: 250px;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
            width: 0;
        }

        #page-content-wrapper {
            padding: 20px;
            position: relative;
        }

        #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
            position: relative;
            margin-right: 0;
        }
    }
</style>

<script>
    var AccountNav = (function () {
        var wWidth;

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#submenu-toggle").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
            });

            getWindowWidth();
            ToggleNavBar();
        });

        $(window).resize(function () {
            getWindowWidth();
            console.log(wWidth);
            ToggleNavBar();
        });

        function ToggleNavBar() {
            if (wWidth >= 768) {
                $("#toggle-navbar").css("display", "none");
            } else {
                $("#toggle-navbar").css("display", "flex");
                if ($("#wrapper").hasClass("toggled")) {
                    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
                }
            }
        }

        function getWindowWidth() {
            wWidth = $(window).width();
        }
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. However, I'm having an issue with the second navbar that toggles the side nav it has a weird spacing issue. there's a large gap above the navbar below the main navbar which removes the toggle-navbars element default height. How would I adjust it to keep its default height?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by `height: 100%` for `#sidebar-wrapper` - we just reduce the height of `#sidebar-wrapper` by the height of the `<header>` which brings us to **one change in your CSS**:

```
height: calc(100% - 64px);
```

complete **snippet** below:

```js
var AccountNav = (function() {
  var wWidth;

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submenu-toggle").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });

    getWindowWidth();
    ToggleNavBar();
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
    getWindowWidth();
    console.log(wWidth);
    ToggleNavBar();
  });

  function ToggleNavBar() {
    if (wWidth >= 768) {
      $("#toggle-navbar").css("display", "none");
    } else {
      $("#toggle-navbar").css("display", "flex");
      if ($("#wrapper").hasClass("toggled")) {
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
      }
    }
  }

  function getWindowWidth() {
    wWidth = $(window).width();
  }
})();
```

```css
html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#wrapper {
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
  padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 250px;
  width: 0;
  height: calc(100% - 64px);
  margin-left: -250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -250px;
}


/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  text-indent: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: #fff
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand a {
  color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
  #wrapper {
    padding-left: 250px;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 0;
  }
  #page-content-wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar--fixed navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark py-1">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand -->
        <a asp-controller="home" asp-action="index" class="navbar-brand">
          <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" style="enable-background: new 0 0 32 32;" xml:space="preserve" fill="white">
                        <g id="logo" class="logo">
                            <path
                                d="M2 20h20v2H2v-2zm2-8h2v7H4v-7zm5 0h2v7H9v-7zm4 0h2v7h-2v-7zm5 0h2v7h-2v-7zM2 7l10-5 10 5v4H2V7zm2 1.236V9h16v-.764l-8-4-8 4zM12 8a1 1 0 1 1 0-2 1 1 0 0 1 0 2z" />
                        </g>
                    </svg> BankNet
        </a>

        <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="nav-link">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Features" class="nav-link">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="false" aria-expanded="false">
                                Utilities
                            </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <a asp-controller="Utilities" asp-action="CurrencyConverter" class="dropdown-item">Currency Converter</a>
                <a asp-controller="Utilities" asp-action="TaxCalculator" class="dropdown-item">Tax
                                    Calculator</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li href="#" class="nav-link">
              <a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Account" class="nav-link">Account</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main role="main" class="pb-3">
    <nav class="navbar p-1" id="toggle-navbar">
      <div class="nav-item">
        <a class="btn btn-dark text-light" id="submenu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
          <li class="sidebar-brand">
            Hello {Name}
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#Accounts">Accounts</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#Transfers">Transfers</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#Loans">Loans</a>
          </li>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#Options">Account options</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <h1>Hello World</h1>
              <h1>Hello World</h1>
              <h1>Hello World</h1>
              <h1>Hello World</h1>
              <h1>Hello World</h1>
              <h1>Hello World</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```